# Filter html content with Spring and Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-security, thymeleaf, spring-boot

How can I filter html content according to the authentication status by using Spring Boot with Spring Security and Thymeleaf?
Note: I'm using Spring boot auto-configuration.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by filter html content? Do you mean that you want certain parts of the html to only be rendered when a user has a certain role?

Comment: Yes, for instance login button and logout button.

Answer (score 2):

What you want can be achieved using Thymeleaf's Spring Security integration (check out this [link](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3) if you haven't already integrated the two).

For example you could do the following:

```
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    This content is only shown to administrators.
</div>
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
    This content is only shown to users.
</div>
```

Comment: This solution won't work: the template engine not render the "sec" keyword (and the auto-config allow by default the security dialect).

Comment: Have you added xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3" to the html tag? If so, have you performed the integration steps that are mentioned in the link above?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-spring4-4.dtd">
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
  xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3"
  lang="it">

Comment: What is the stack trace that you are getting?

Comment: Nothing. When I check the source code of the page, I can see the "sec" tag.

Comment: Mmm... Should I set the Spring Sec filters?

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot or vanilla Spring

Comment: Spring Boot with autoconf.

Comment: Try importing spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf in your build script

Comment: But is it normal the 404 error on http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3?

Comment: I think that it is just a namespace, it's meant to actually be a page

Comment: Ok, I've found the issue: I have to add thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3 on my pom.xml.